# create form from 2 models python django: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, errno

I am trying to create a form from 2 models using python and django. 
Below shows my models:

```
# Create your models here.
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action name", max_length=50)
    keywords = models.CharField("Keywords", max_length=50)
    object = models.CharField("Object", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uploadDate = models.DateField("Date", default=get_current_date)
    UploadedBy = models.CharField("UploadedBy", max_length=50, default="")

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, default="") 
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

and the form classes:

```
class ActionForm(ModelForm):
    #bind form to Action model
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ['name','keywords', 'object', 'UploadedBy', 'uploadDate']

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Image
        fields =['image']
```

The code in views which creates the page from createForm.html template:

```
def actioncreate(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    #create the object - Actionform 
    form = ActionForm;
    form2 = ImageForm;
    #pass into it 
    return render(request,'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form, 'form2':form2})
elif request.method == "POST":
    # take all of the user data entered to create a new action instance in the table
    form = ActionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form2 = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if  form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        #prepare action model  
        act = form.save(commit=False)
        #set the action_id Foreignkey 
        act.action_id = form2.save()
        act.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/actions')
    else:
        form = ActionForm()
        form2 = ImageForm;
        return render(request,'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form, 'form2':form2 })
```

form template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    {{ form2.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>  
    <button name="cancel" onclick="navigate({% url 'home' %})">Cancel</button>                
</form>
```

The form displays fine when the page is accessed, however once submitted I get this error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory

and it doesnt seem to like the line:

```
act.action_id = form2.save()
```

The models created most definiely has all of the fields I am referring to and although I am getting this error the first half (ActionForm) saves into the database, 
but not the imageForm. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Error:

```
OSError at /actions/create
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/create
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception Location: C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py in _save, line 248
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2',
'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\Scripts',
'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env',
'C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\FINALYEAR\\CSbackup\\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\\MyActionDefiner2\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 28 Jan 2016 15:24:04 +0000
```

Traceback

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/create

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\app\views.py" in actioncreate
53.             act.action_id = form2.save()
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
459.                              construct=False)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save_instance
105.         instance.save()
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
846.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
885.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
973.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
931.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
314.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
93.             self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in save
63.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Documents\FINALYEAR\CSbackup\MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy\MyActionDefiner2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in _save
248.                     fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)

Exception Type: OSError at /actions/create
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a sub-directory of MEDIA_ROOT to upload to that exists on your local file system. Check what is being returned by the get_upload_file_name function and check that that is a sub-directory of MEDIA_ROOT (defined in settings.py) on your local file system:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, default="")
```

See here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: The media root is: 
 MEDIA_ROOT =   'Users/Rebecca/Documents/FINALYEAR/CSbackup/MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy/MyActionDefiner2/app/static'

and the getUploadFileName:
 def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
  return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(timezone.now()).replace('.','_'), filename)
  
uploaded_files is a sub directory of original path. 
The file uploading worked when I originally created just the one file upload form, but now its getting errors when submitting 2 forms together

Comment: Are you missing C:/ in MEDIA_ROOT? Try MEDIA_ROOT='C:/Users/Rebecca/Documents/FINALYEAR/CSbackup/MyActionDefiner3 - 2tblWorking - Copy/MyActionDefiner2/app/static'

Comment: Also check what str(timezone.now()) is returning. Isn't it something like 2016-01-29 11:19:42.897000+00:00 ? Then your upload path will contain characters like + : which would make it invalid. Try str(timezone.now().date())

Comment: Ah yes the timezone was returning an invalid argument, I've got that bit working now, thanks. But when the form is submitted, it trys to save image.id, image.image(filename)and returns null for image.action_id
I am getting the error: **null value in column "action_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, uploaded_files/29_personrunning_Hq8IAQi.jpg, null).**

Comment: I need to populate the third column with the action.id which django creates itself on submitting the first 'form'. Do you know is there a way that value can be passed to be related in the image table?  image.action_id is declared initially as a foreignKey.

Comment: That's a separate question, please mark this one as accepted. It's because you are setting action_id on you action object not image object e.g. act.action_id = form2.save()